# retrieving playlists via youtube data api - have to authenticate request each time

Tags: python, google-oauth

```
def YouTube_Playlist(phrase):
  scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]
  try:
       say("Getting Playlist from  Youtube")
        # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
       os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

       api_service_name = "youtube"
       api_version = "v3"
       client_secrets_file = configuration['Google_client_secret_file']
  # Get credentials and create an API client
       flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, scopes)
       credentials = flow.run_console()
       youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(api_service_name,api_version, credentials=credentials)

   #google_cloud_api_key = configuration['Google_cloud_api_key']
   #youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(api_service_name, api_version,developerKey=google_cloud_api_key)
       request = youtube.playlists().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails",
        maxResults=25,
        mine=True)
       response = request.execute()

       no_items = response['pageInfo']['totalResults']
       playlist_name = phrase.rpartition("from")[0].replace('playlist','').rstrip().lstrip()
       playlist_id = ""
       print("Playlist:",playlist_name)
       print("No of Playlists",no_items)
       for x in range(no_items):
          title = response['items'][x]['snippet']['title']
          print("index",x)
          print("title",title)
          if title in playlist_name:
            playlist_id = response['items'][x]['id']
            print("Matched Playlist:",playlist_id)
            break
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    say('Encountered an exception please check the logs.')
```

This code was from the api explorer on googles developer website and it works fine. Except I have to authenticate the request each time I call the api. It gives you a url to visit then you need to tick all the scopes you want to authorise. It then gives a code for you to type into the commandline.

This isn't ideal since I am trying to build a headless smart speaker. Hence I won't have a screen and keyboard to authenticate the request with.

Is there not a way I can save the token so I dont have to reauthenticate? If there is a way to save the token, how do I then use the saved token in furture requests?